# Linux - Replacing spaces in the file names

Tags: linux, replace, command, filenames, spaces

I have a number of files in a folder, and I want to replace every space character in all file names with underscores. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

This should do it:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" `echo $file | tr ' ' '_'` ; done
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It claimed identical files existed (with the wrong filenames). E.g. trying to rename `1 - foo.jpg` and my folder already had `1.jpg` in it.

Comment: I find backticks bit hard to read when they are near quotes. The same but more readable would be `for file in *; do mv "$file" $(echo $file | tr ' ' '_') ; done`

Comment: Note: This is run from WITHIN the directory whose files' names you want to update. Alternatively, you can change `*` to `PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY`.

Answer (score 93):

I prefer to use the command 'rename', which takes Perl-style regexes:

```
rename "s/ /_/g" *
```

You can do a dry run with the -n flag:

```
rename -n "s/ /_/g" *
```

Comment: this will work *if* you have the perl-style rename and not the simpler redhat/fedora one

Comment: the fedora version would be `rename " " "_" *`

Comment: `rename` not available in OSX it appears.

Comment: On macOS 10.12.3, `rename` is available.

Comment: For some reason `rename` does not do a single thing on my CentOS box. Either with regex or not.

Comment: Seeing this error on fish: `No matches for wildcard '*'.  (Tip: empty matches are allowed in 'set', 'count', 'for'.)`

Comment: @Etienne Low-Décarie:  brew install rename

Comment: If your folder contains files that start with `-` you need to add `--` before the `*`

Comment: @DavidDean The rename on Arch Linux will only replace the first occurrence (not very convenient for files/directories with multiple spaces). It has the same syntax as the fedora one, so I suspect they may be the same one. But perl-rename can be installed.

Answer (score 20):

Use sh...

```
for i in *' '*; do   mv "$i" `echo $i | sed -e 's/ /_/g'`; done
```

If you want to try this out before pulling the trigger just change `mv` to `echo mv`.

Answer (score 6):

What if you want to apply the replace task **recursively**? How would you do that?

Well, I just found the answer myself. Not the most elegant solution, (also tries to rename files that do not comply with the condition) but it works. (BTW, in my case I needed to rename the files with '%20', not with an underscore)

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type d | while read N
do
     (
           cd "$N"
           if test "$?" = "0"
           then
               for file in *; do mv "$file" ${file// /%20}; done
           fi
     )
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use bash:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" ${file// /_}; done
```

Comment: when i tried, i got
mv: when moving multiple files, last argument must be a directory
Try `mv --help' for more information.
mv: when moving multiple files, last argument must be a directory
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: Again error 
mv: missing file argument
Try `mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing file argument
Try `mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing file argument
Try `mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing file argument
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution:

```
ls | awk '{printf("\"%s\"\n", $0)}' | sed 'p; s/\ /_/g' | xargs -n2 mv
```

1. uses awk to add quotes around the name of the file
2. uses sed to replace space with underscores; prints the original name with quotes(from awk); then the substituted name
3. xargs takes 2 lines at a time and passes it to mv

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this, assuming all of your files were .txt's:

```
for files in *.txt; do mv “$files” `echo $files | tr ‘ ‘ ‘_’`; done
```

Comment: got the below error
tr: two strings must be given when translating
mv: missing file argument
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: Agin error tr: too many arguments
Try `tr --help' for more information.
mv: missing file argument
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Quote your variables:

```
for file in *; do echo mv "'$file'" "${file// /_}"; done
```

Remove the "echo" to do the actual rename.

Comment: It is echoing the mv commands prperly, but not really renaming the file!

Comment: removing echo produces error like 
mv: cannot stat `\'1130 lake micigan view.jpg\'': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `\'1130_1_bedroom_floor_plan.jpg\'': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `\'1130_BedPicture_8.jpg\'': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `\'1130_diningroom_table.jpg\'': No such file or directory

Comment: Linux
Linux 2.6.9-42.0.3.EL.wh1smp #1 SMP Fri Aug 14 15:48:17 MDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

To rename all the files with a `.py` extension use,

`find . -iname "*.py" -type f | xargs -I% rename "s/ /_/g" "%"`

Sample output,

```
$ find . -iname "*.py" -type f                                                     
./Sample File.py
./Sample/Sample File.py
$ find . -iname "*.py" -type f | xargs -I% rename "s/ /_/g" "%"
$ find . -iname "*.py" -type f                                                     
./Sample/Sample_File.py
./Sample_File.py
```

Comment: By far this is the only solution that worked on mac/zsh based terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace `' '` with `'_'` in every folder and file name recursivelly in Linux with Python >= 3.5. Change `path_to_your_folder` with your path.

Only list files and folders:

```
python -c "import glob;[print(x) for x in glob.glob('path_to_your_folder/**', recursive=True)]"
```

Replace `' '` with `'_'` in every folder and file name

```
python -c "import os;import glob;[os.rename(x,x.replace(' ','_')) for x in glob.glob('path_to_your_folder/**', recursive=True)]"
```

With Python < 3.5, you can install [glob2](https://pypi.org/project/glob2/)

```
pip install glob2
python -c "import os;import glob2;[os.rename(x,x.replace(' ','_')) for x in glob2.glob('path_to_your_folder/**')]"
```

Comment: this didn't work for subfolders which had spaces in them

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to replace a string (space character in your case) with another string in `Linux` is using `sed`. You can do it as follows

```
sed -i 's/\s/_/g' *
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not address the question.