# Removing white spaces within a file name after a specific text using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have few files, having files name in the below form:

```
export_<directory_name>_system.indexes .json
```

Here the directory keeps changing,so it could be anything

However _system.indexes is constant

Notice the space between 'indexes and '.json'.

I want to get rid of the space in between them, so the expected file name is as below

```
export_<directory_name>_system.indexes.json
```

I have tried the below:

```
echo export_direcotoryName_system.indexes .json | sed 's/\s\+//'
```

All though it does remove the space..but it also removes space from other files which i do not want.

How can restrict the removal only to files having *system.indexes* in their filenames

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux - Replacing spaces in the file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806868/linux-replacing-spaces-in-the-file-names)

Answer (score 1):

With prename:

```
prename -n 's/system.indexes .json/system.indexes.json/' *.json
```

if everythink looks fine, remove `-n`.